Is it possible to make Debezium engine work with Mysql binlog files without connecting directly to the data base
I am looking for an alternate way for Debezium to work with mysql database
that not involving connect directly to the database and reading bin_logs and work offline with files
or maybe work like an ETL with DB Snapshot
the Reason: after Upgrading from aurora 2 to 3 we add a degrade in performance
also we have a really bad history with bin-log replication
a solution architect in AWS advise US to stay with bin-log MIX
and further more this warning on AWS

follow github , discord channel messages search for medium blog and still not found anything
